Appium server error:- Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure
My configuration of appium is not working gives "Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure".
My code:-
package Bizupautomation.bizup;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.time.Duration;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.options.UiAutomator2Options;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder;

public class Base {
    
    public AndroidDriver driver;
    public AppiumDriverLocalService service;
    
    @BeforeClass
    public void ConfigureAppium() throws MalformedURLException, URISyntaxException
    {
        //Run appium server automatically
        service = new AppiumServiceBuilder().withAppiumJS(new File("C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\lib\\main.js"))
                .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1").usingPort(4723).build();
                
        //Create capablities
        UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
        options.setDeviceName("samsung SM-E146B");
        //options.setDeviceName("Xiaomi Redmi Y1");
        options.setApp("C:\\Users\\lenovo\\eclipse-workspace\\Appium\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\Bizup-2.14.3-debug.apk");

        
        driver =new AndroidDriver(new URI("http://127.0.0.1:4723").toURL(), options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));  
    
    }
    
    @AfterClass
    public void TearDown()
    {
        driver.quit();
        service.stop();
    }
    
    public void HomeWait()
    {
        WebDriverWait  wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeContains(driver.findElement(By.id("com.sot.bizup.debug:id/mtTopAll")), "text", "All"));
    }

}


When I run the appium inspector then it start correctly with the same configuration, but I don't know why this configuration is not started.
I also try:-

updating all the dependencies
restart or reboot the system and devise
Change the server path

Server logs when started manually:-
C:\Users\lenovo>appium
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v2.5.1
[Appium] The autodetected Appium home path: C:\Users\lenovo\.appium
[Appium] Attempting to load driver uiautomator2...
[Appium] Requiring driver at C:\Users\lenovo\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\build\index.js
[Appium] AndroidUiautomator2Driver has been successfully loaded in 4.241s
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on http://0.0.0.0:4723
[Appium] You can provide the following URLs in your client code to connect to this server:
[Appium]        http://192.168.0.114:4723/
[Appium]        http://127.0.0.1:4723/ (only accessible from the same host)
[Appium] Available drivers:
[Appium]   - uiautomator2@2.45.1 (automationName 'UiAutomator2')
[Appium] No plugins have been installed. Use the "appium plugin" command to install the one(s) you want to use.

